# How do I get my Dicord bot to work on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Currently I have a working Discord bot, that works completely fine.
I set up an app service for my node project and when I deploy it, my bot comes online and works completely fine. But after 230 seconds, my bot goes offline. At first I thought maybe there's still a bug in my code, but when checking the logs, I see that the bot went offline because of this:

```
2020-05-11T17:00:05.681Z ERROR - Container xxx for site xx did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 231.0262877 sec
2020-05-11T17:00:05.699Z ERROR - Container xxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-05-11T17:00:05.873Z INFO  - Stopping site xx because it failed during startup.
```

Now I'm not sure why this happens. The bot did start and works fine, also the bot has some stuff scheduled that it does every 2 minutes, so it's definitely not inactive.

Now I searched around a bit and saw there's an option to use "Always On" in the configuration of my app service, but since I'm using the free service (I'm a student), I can't enable this option. Is there an other way to fix my issue?

The other option I came across was to just use a VM and host my code there. Now that would probably work, but I feel like the service I'm currently using is made exactly for what I'm using it for and the workflow is pretty easy (I can just deploy my code straight out of VS Code).

I'm brand new to using Azure so maybe I'm just using the wrong service for my project, but maybe there's just some stupid thing I didn't catch. Thank you in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your Web App expects that your site will listen on a port and respond to a request, or it thinks it is unhealthy. So you need to make sure you stand up a webserver that listens on the port (8080 in this case) and responds with something (doesn't really matter what).

You will still get shutdown eventually by the always on stuff. The only way to avoid that is make sure you get a web request frequently enough it doesn't shut down.

You might want to try out Azure Container Instances instead if you don't need a web server. It doesn't have any restrictions on only being online when you're getting traffic, so you don't need to worry about always on.